# subversion Duplicate Branch Folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I am using tortoise SVN

I must be using svn wrong but here is the issue:

So I have a Trunk right, and I create Branch1 from it.

Now if I do a svn update on Trunk I will see the branch folder in the trunk folder. Ok fine.

Now if someone else creates a branch called Branch2.  I then see Branch2 show up in the trunk folder after a svn update. Ok...also fine.

However, here is when things diverge.  If those branches have been out there for a while being developed and other people are making update to the Trunk then the smart thing to do after a while is to Merge Down from trunk into the two branches.

now if you have switched to the branch folder as your working directory and you shift + right click on the branch folder and choose Merge All it will pull down everything from trunk into your branch which includes the Branch1 and Branch2 folders.

This seems odd to me.

It begins folder inception.  If this is done a few times you end up getting a nested mess of folders inside eachother.

I have looked at all kinds of documentation and I cannot figure it out.

I thought that you could solve this problem with Merge depth.  where it should be set to working copy and thus should only merge the files you have in the branch with the trunk.  Not pull itself from trunk into itself.

Because after a while you get:

```
                              |----Branch1
                  |----Branch1|____Branch2
      |----Branch2|
      |           |           |----Branch1
      |           |____Branch2|____Branch2
Trunk |           
      |                       |----Branch1
      |           |____Branch1|____Branch2
      |----Branch1|
                  |           |----Branch1
                  |____Branch2|____Branch2
```

There is like no end to it.

I tried playing with Merge depth but that had no effect.

Comment: I think the branches (`branch1`, `branch2`, etc) should have been created _outside_ of `trunk`. SVN Standard layout would use `branches/branch1`, `branches/branch2` (I'm more of a git guy so take that with a grain of salt, just in case).